# mysql ERROR 1071 (Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes) in simple dump-import setting

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1071

dump mysql db on server 1

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.54, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
$ mysqldump -u root -p db > db.sql
```

import on server 2

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
$ mysql -u root -p db < db.sql
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 807: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

I know there is a lot of questions and answers on this error but it still leaves me puzzled.

Can it be a version problem? I suspect no.

If I run it with --force option, it gets even wierder:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 807: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 847: Table 'db.users' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 848: Table 'db.users' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 849: Table 'db.users' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 850: Table 'db.users' doesn't exist
```

what is going on?

I mean apart from solving this, I would like to understand what settings affect a simple dump-import act and why can those settings not be explicit in my dump file and be set t import.

I prefer not having to debug actual errors, this must be solveable on high level.

UPDATE: SOLUTION
as Frederic pointed me to the right direction. Basically my dump was trying to set db with INNODB engine, but mysql on server 2 had in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
```

by simply deleting this option and restarting mysqld, my import ran without a croak.
I am very sad such a simple thing like an unavailable engine is not worthy of warning or error rather than key length issue caused by silently falling back to myISAM. Hmm. So time to switch to posgresql? mongo? :)

Comment: Are you using innodb? Is innodb enabled on both machines ? (check the has_innodb variable in the output from show variables)

Comment: @FrederickCheung YES on server 1, DISABLED on server 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like innodb is disabled on the second machine, so mysql silently falls back to myisam which has different limitations: 1000 bytes per key instead of 3500

The last time I saw something like this it was because of a configuration problem: mysql can't setup innodb on startup so it disables innodb. Check your mysql error log, it should flag any problems encountered during startup. For example, innodb will refuse to initialize if the `innodb_log_file_size` setting doesn't match the size of the log files (`ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, ...)

Comment: why is it a problem if innodb is disabled? according to sources, its limitation is 767 bytes not 1000. I checked the mysqld logs but gives no complaints. thanks for help

Comment: Innodb limit is 767 per column, 3500 for the total key length (eg a key on 2 765 byte columns (such as a UTF8 varchar(255) is fine. Myisam limit is 1000 for all columns, so a key on 2 UTF8 varchar(255) would hit that 1000 byte limit. MySQL can scatter its errors across several error logs - make sure you checked them all

Comment: Thanks for your help Fred. i cannot find other logs than /var/lib/mysql/domain.err and even this i had to find by looking into /usr/bin/mysqld_safe script code. So if you think it is an innodb issue, could you advise me how I enable that for my db.

Answer (score 7):

This work for me.

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p

use DATABASENAME;

set global innodb_large_prefix=on;
set global innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
set global innodb_file_per_table=true;
```

[Error: “#1071 – Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes” when import mysql db](https://hungnhotblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/error-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes-when-import-mysql-db/)

Answer (score 0):

Besides, if your system is 64bit and you are running MySQL from yum (repository default), you will see this error when attemp restore database from other systems. I don't know why "yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-server", them just run with 32bit.

So, in this case please install and use MySQL from Percona or Marina (of course is 64bit version)